# Git stash and apply to a branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-stash

So I make changes in 'branch - A', and pushed that branch remotely.
Now I checkout a new 'branch - B' and begin work on it.
But, now I need to work on branch-A again.

This is what i plan to do:

1. While my current branch is B I will do:
   git stash.
2. git checkout branch-A

After I am done working on branch A, 
I would do git stash ( to save changes of branch-A).

Now here is my question, If I need to work on branch-B again, how should i do git stash pop ?

I dont want `A's` stash to be applied on branch B ?

Comment: Should this be considered a bad practice? As far as I am concerned, I prefer to commit my changes (and add a `WIP` tag in front of the commit message) before changing branches.

Comment: Interesting suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the `stash list` (follow stack). `git stash apply` default to `stash@{0}`. If you want another previous stash then, just mention `stash@<number>`.

```
$ git checkout B
# do some change here
$ git add .
$ git stash save 'stash of B'

$ git checkout A
# do some change here
$ git add .
$ git stash save 'stash of A'

$ git checkout B  
$ git stash list                # see the stash list with message
$ git stash apply stash@{1}     # B's stash will be applied

$ git stash drop stash@{1}      # remove B's stash from stash stack
```

Comment: Also note that on some git implementations (at least Windows), the stash name needs to be in quotes: `git stash apply "stash@{1}"`